# How to manipulate HCL abstract syntax tree?

Tags: go, terraform, abstract-syntax-tree, hcl

I'm writing a compiler using [HCL](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl) (HashiCorp Configuration Language) and I'm trying to manipulate the AST so that I can add my custom logic.

```
hclParseTree, err := hcl.Parse(input)
check(err)
spew.Dump(hclParseTree)
```

I've only managed to print all the tree elements by using [go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew).

[Documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/hcl) is relatively vague and there are few supporting articles on the web. I tried to follow [this](http://jen20.com/2015/09/07/using-hcl-part-1.html) one, but the syntax is deprecated (written in 2015).

How could I achieve something like this?

```
item := hclParseTree.Get("item")
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I have a feeling you're looking for https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/ast#WalkFunc